# Manipulate async call with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I have a  calendar that displays events from MongoDB.
Every time a user click on prev or next button, i do an asynchronous call and than i reset the current array of days and events; but if a user clicks on a button several times are shown double results.

```
 $scope.next = function () {
     //reset array
    $scope.gridOptions.data=[];

    //date of week

    myService.dbAction(dt3,dt4).then(function (data) {

      check(data);
      $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.setts;//update data
    }, function (error) {
      console.error('ERROR: ' + error);
    })
 }
```

I want only the last week events , how to do that?

Comment: It depends. Do you want to block the user from clicking prev/next until the results have returned? Or do you want to let them click the buttons as fast as they want to, but only keep the latest information?

Comment: I want to display the latest information

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to add a `fetchPending` flag. Use it to avoid duplicate fetches.

```
$scope.next = function () {
    if ($scope.fetchPending) return;
    $scope.fetchPending = true;
    //reset array
    $scope.gridOptions.data=[];

    //date of week

    myService.dbAction(dt3,dt4).then(function (data) {

      check(data);
      $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.setts;//update data

    }).catch ( function (error) {
       console.error('ERROR: ' + error);
    }).finally( function () {
       $scope.fetchPending = false;
    })
 }
```